# How to create tabs for django admin?

Tags: python, django, database, web

How to create tabs for admin languages.

Example like:

`Change book`

`English` `Japanese`

*Some models*

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are implementing translation for model fields, use [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation)

It provides a graceful way of implementing translatable fields as well as integrate well with django admin through [TranslationAdmin](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html) class providing the tabs that I guess you are looking for.

[image: Language Tabs in Django admin using django-modeltranslation]